# Concurrency in Hashtables, and fail-safe behavior

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, hashtable

I was reading about Hashtables and this question struck me. Hashtables are synchronized, so is an iterator on a Hashtable fail-safe?

Also, for fail-safe Collections, when multiple threads try to access a Collection, you won't get a ConcurrentModificationException because each thread is working on its own copy of it. I was wondering does this mean, that an actual physical copy of the Collection is created in the memory for each thread?

Comment: Please get in the habit of adding the relevant language tag.

Comment: sure, sorry about that.

Comment: just to clarify, ConcurrentModificationException (despite its name) _really has nothing to do with threads_.  thread-safety and "iteration during modification safety" (CME) are two orthogonal concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Ummm ... if by "fail-safe" you mean that you can't get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, then then the answer is No.  You *can* get that exception with a `Hashtable` when you use an `Iterator` on it.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) states that explicitly.

---

> Also, for fail-safe Collections, when multiple threads try to access a Collection, you won't get a ConcurrentModificationException because each thread is working on its own copy of it.

(You seem to be quoting or summarizing that from somewhere.  Whatever, I don't think it is accurate.)

> I was wondering does this mean, that an actual physical copy of the Collection is created in the memory for each thread?

In some cases the iterator is working off a copy that is not going to be modified.  In other cases, the iterator is working off something that *could* be modified and/or that doesn't represent a consistent snapshot of the collection at all.  It really depends on how the "fail-safe" behaviour is specified *for the specific collection class that you are talking about*.  (And one of the good things about the collection classes is that they clearly specify what you can and cannot rely on.  You just need to read the specifications *carefully* to make sure that you really understand them!!)

---

> Oh, so the iterator in Hashtable is fail-fast but the enumerator is fail-safe.

The first part is correct.  The second is incorrect.

The `Enumeration` objects returned by `Hashtable` are NOT guaranteed to be fail-safe.  What the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) state is that the `Enumeration` are not fail-fast.  What actually happens when you modify a `Hashtable` and enumerate it at the same time is *not specified*.  (If you really want to know, look at the source code for the specific version of Java you are using.)

Comment: Oh, so the iterator in Hashtable is fail-fast but the enumerator is fail-safe. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yes, I read that in a Java blog. But your response leaves me all the more curious. So, how is fail-safe behavior of a Collection actually implemented?

Comment: @Setafire - like I said.  It depends on what the specified behaviour actually is!  There is no single answer.

Comment: The enumerator is only "fail-safe" if "fail-safe" means that it doesn't _tell_ you that it's corrupted and doesn't work anymore.  It's no safer; it's frankly the opposite of safer.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - precisely!!!  And note that the javadocs DO NOT SAY that the enumerator / enumeration is "fail-safe".  That claim is a figment of someone's imagination.  In fact, one of the reasons that they added the Iterator class was to clear up this mess ... by introducing the fail-fast behaviour.  Prior to that, the simultaneous update and enumeration of Hashtable and Vector instances was a major source of bugs.

Comment: So what is accurate meaning of "fail-safe"?

Comment: @Deqing - Fail-safe means that it won't fail; i.e. safe from failure.  It can also mean, that it will work *in spite of* failures (in something else).

Answer (score 0):

RTFM:

> The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the Hashtable is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future. The Enumerations returned by Hashtable's keys and elements methods are not fail-fast.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

In other words, iteration over a `Hashtable` is no safer than iteration over an unsynchronized `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> hashtable = new Hashtable<>();
Integer a = hashtable.put("a", 1);
Integer a1 = hashtable.put("b", 2);
Integer a3 = hashtable.put("c", 3);
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = hashtable.entrySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
        hashtable.put("d",4);
        iterator.next();
    }
```

1. Hashtable is not concurrent, it is synchronized.
2. Hashtable is fail-fast, if you iterate the Hashtable while add or remove one element without using the iterator, then you will get ConcurrentModificationException.